# How in zen coding in PhpStorm, you can add multiple classes at the same time to a particular div?

Tags: html

I have to apply two classes for a particular HTML element, give me the exact way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply type the tag and add two or more classes just by putting dot in front of each class.
for ex. div.room.hello turns to `<div class="room hello"></div>`